# Displaying multiple lines from while loop in one output box

Tags: java

My assignment asks to print all values from 1-10 using while loops in one output dialog box, with each number appearing on a separate line. So far I have:

```
int i=1;

    while (i <= 10)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }
```

and it displays 1-10 on separate lines but that's in the command prompt window. I need it to be displayed on one output box. How would I do that? 
Forgot to mention, I know how to display the output in a dialog box, however it displays it one by one in separate boxes rather than in just one. How would I make it display in only one and not 10 different boxes?

Comment: Do you know how to display a dialog box? Do you know how to concatenate strings?

Comment: I know how to display a dialog box, not really sure what the second question means so I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be found in the Java Docs. The classes, as well as how to use them can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Be sure to import this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't 100% clear. I know how to use dialog boxes, I just don't know how to display the output in one single box like it does in the command prompt. The way I would do it has 1-10 displayed one by one in different boxes but I need it in only one.

Comment: ...where are you creating the dialog box in your code? If it's inside the for loop, that is your problem. Your question does not have enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you're just printing to the console, all you have to do is change `System.out.println` to `System.out.print`:

```
int i = 1;

while (i <= 10) 
{
    System.out.print(i);
    i++;
}
```

An alternative way to do it is this:

```
String s = "";
int i = 1;

while (i <= 10) {
    s += i;
    i++;
}

System.out.println(s);
```